# using SqlConnection.Open inside using () {} block?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Do I need to use `SqlConnection.Open()` inside:

```
using (SqlConnection var = new SqlConnection()) 
{
   //my operations
}
```

?

What happens if I don't dispose this connection by `SqlConnection.Close()` function?

Comment: If you don't close or dispose the connection, either by explicitly invoking close/dispose methods or implicitly with a using block, the connection won't get returned to the pool until garbage collection kicks in.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you need to `Open` your connection inside the `using` block.

If you don't explicitly `Close()` the connection, the end of the `using` block will do it for you as the using disposes of the connection. When a connection is disposed it is automatically closed.

Answer (score 5):

The `using` statement is just syntactic sugar which ensures that `Dispose` gets called on the `IDisposable` instance no matter what, so in your case `using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())` is roughly equivalent to (as per MSDN):

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();

try
{
    // Operations.
}
finally
{
    if (connection != null)
    {
        connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In the case of `SqlConnection` `Dispose` and `Close` calls are actually equivalent, so a call to `Close` would be redundant within a `using (SqlConnection)` block.

Calling `Open`, on the other hand, will still be necessary in many scenarios (before a call to `ExecuteReader`, `ExecuteScalar`, `ExecuteNonQuery`, for example). The `using` statement has no effect on whether or not you need to explicitly open the connection - only on whether or not you need to explicitly close it.

Answer (score 0):

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of
>   IDisposable objects

`using`  Implements IDisposable Internally

```
using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("myCOnstr")) 
{
con.open();
using(SqlCommand con=new SqlCommand("myCmd",con)) 
{
//......Insert/Update /Delete

}


}
```